# Using nested dictionaries to store user defined graph

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get the user to enter a graph manually as opposed to using it 'pre-existing' in the code, for use in my Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I have done this but would like some feedback on its implementation and user friendliness. In addition is there a more efficient way of entering a graph into a nested dictionary ? If so how ?.

Key points about code

- Data must be stored using nested dictionaries
- A loop would be a zero e.g b-b is 0 not left blank, but this only occurs if a loop is present in user graph otherwise its ignored.
- Ideally I would not like to use anything inside existing libraries before coding it myself to get a better understanding of what is happening

Many Thanks. 
Edit: repeat requirement no longer needed.

```
{'A': {'C': 1, 'B': 5}, 'D': {}, 'B': {'D': 2}, 'C': {'D': 9}}
```

^ Desired output for nodes also current output.

```
nodes = {}


def add_node():
    entered_graph = False
    while not entered_graph:
        source_node = input("Enter a source node: ")
        num_neighbours = int(input("Enter how many neighbours this node has"
                                   "including previously entered nodes: "))
        nodes[source_node] = {}
        for neighbour in range(num_neighbours):
            neighbour = input("Enter neighbor node: ")
            distance = int(input("Enter distance from source node to this neighbor node: "))
            nodes[source_node][neighbour] = distance
        end_loop = input("Enter y to finish graph entry: ")
        end_loop = end_loop.lower()
        if end_loop == "y":
            entered_graph = True

add_node()
print(nodes)
```

Comment: "Data must be stored using nested dictionaries" why? I would create a dictionary with tuples as keys `(from_location_id, to_location_id)`.

Comment: Especially if you're saying that this is a symmetric graph, such that a-->b == b-->a. Then you only need to store one of those pairs and test for both i.e. (a, b) or (b, a). This would be really important on big problems in terms of memory. Nested dictionaries with single locations as a key would lead to _massive_ duplication that's unnecessary.

Comment: Indeed I have rectified this in my algorithm so there is no need to add each arc twice now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only want users to enter every edge once, then you can just store it twice.

```
edges = {}
while True:
    edge = input('Enter an edge as Node names separated by a space followed by a number ("exit" to exit): ')
    if edge == 'exit':
        break
    node1, node2, weight = edge.split()
    weight = float(weight)
    if node1 not in edges:
        edges[node1] = {}
    if node2 not in edges:
        edges[node2] = {}
    edges[node1][node2] = weight
    edges[node2][node1] = weight
```

User enters each edge once as `"A B 3.5"`

Comment: Learnt something new thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Khanacademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/graph-representation/a/representing-graphs) has a pretty good page on different ways to represent graphs.

For an undirected graph (a => b and b => a) I would personally look at using an edge list. It can be sorted to improve lookup efficiency, and it is more memory efficient than other methods such as an adjacency table